# Table CSS style - Block inheritance and design suggestions

Tags: html, css, inheritance, nested-table

First of all, this is not a post for the faint hearted. Please prepare yourself for lousy syntax and horrible HTML structure. If you're still with me, thank you brave soul.

See, I have this table where I want to display information, but I can't get it to look like I want it to look.

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wccrjh6d/

Had to include some code because of the fiddle:

```
table {
    font:normal 12 px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:0;
    margin:0 0 1em;
    color:#000;
    }
table a {
    color:#523A0B;
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    }
table a:visited {
    color:#444;
    font-weight:normal;
    }
table a:visited:after {
    content:"\00A0\221A";
    }
table a:hover {
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    }
.bigiptable > thead > tr > th,
.bigiptable > thead > tr > td {
    border:1px solid #523A0B;
    border-width:1px 0;
    background:#EBE5D9;
    }
.bigiptable > thead > tr > th > input,
.bigiptable > thead > tr > td > input {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:80%;
    }
.bigiptable > head > tr > th,
.bigiptable > head > tr > td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1px;
}

.bigiptable table a table th {
    border:1px solid #523A0B;
    border-width:1px 0;
    background:#EBE5D9;
    }
.bigiptable > thead > tr > th {
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:normal;
    padding:0.25em 0.5em;
    text-align:left;
    }
.bigiptable > thead > tr > th > input {
    font: normal 12px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:normal;
    text-align:left;
    background:#EBE5D9;
    border:0px;
    }
.bigiptable > tbody > tr > th,
.bigiptable > tbody > tr > td {
    padding:0.25em 0.5em;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:center;
    }
.bigiptable > tbody > tr > th {
    font-weight:normal;
    white-space:nowrap;
    }
.bigiptable tbody tr th a:link,
.bigiptable tbody tr th a:visited {
    font-weight:bold;
    }
.bigiptable tbody td,
.bigiptable tbody th {
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-width:1px 0;
    }
.bigiptable tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th,
.bigiptable tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td {
    border-color:#EBE5D9;
    background:#F7F4EE;
    }
.bigiptable tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > th,
.bigiptable tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > td {
    background:#ffffff  ;
    }
.generated {
    font-family: Georgia, Times,serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:0.8em;
    font-style: italic;
}

a.memberinfo {color:#000; text-decoration:none;}
a.memberinfo b {display:none;}
a.memberinfo:hover {border:0; position:relative; z-index:500; text-decoration:none; border-color:#000; }
a.memberinfo:hover b {display:block; position:absolute; top:20px; left:-25px; padding:5px; font-weight:normal; color:#000; border:1px solid #000; background:#ffffee;white-space:nowrap;}
a.memberinfo:hover b em.outer {position:absolute; left:20px; top:-8px; width:0; height:0; display:block; background:transparent; border-left:7px dashed transparent; border-right:7px dashed transparent; border-bottom:7px solid #000; overflow:hidden; z-index:100;}
a.memberinfo:hover b em.inner {position:absolute; left:20px; top:-7px; width:0; height:0; display:block; background:transparent; border-left:7px dashed transparent; border-right:7px dashed transparent; border-bottom:7px solid #ffffee; overflow:hidden;; z-index:100;}
```

As you can see there's nested tables and the rows in the inner table is also affected by the css styles, and I'd like to remove the background color and the upper + lower border. I've been fiddling around trying to block inheritance but so far I've been unable to.

For a view of the full table (obfuscated):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q9xw.png

I'd like to keep the HTML structure somewhat intact if possible.
Any suggestions on how to make it more readable is appreciated!

/Patrik

Comment: To set properties on the inner table, just set them with CSS rules that have greater precedence that now take effect. If problems remain, reduce the issue to the simplest possible case, post the code that demonstrates what you have tried, and explain how it fails.

Comment: Kiitos Jukka, I will try that!